# OpenCV 3.0 cudaarithm missing?

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded pre-built OpenCV 3.0 from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/)

According to the docs, the CUDA versions of functions such as `copyMakeBorder` should be located in cudaarithm module. But the module is nowhere to be seen - searching the include dir for `copyMakeBorder` only comes up with the regular version.

Is proper CUDA support not included in the pre-built package?

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have CUDA installed anyway?

Comment: Yes, I've used it with Theano before. I am now rebuilding OpenCV (3.1) from scratch anyway, will see how that goes. Unfortunately, the pre-built 3.1 only has libraries for VS15 from what I can tell.